# Nginx 1.9.3 with Openssl 1.0.2d Issue ngx_event_openssl.c:2945: undefined reference to `X509_check_host'

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, openssl

We recently updated our openssl to 1.0.2d and tried to compile nginx 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 but we got he following error:

-lpthread -lcrypt /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtilsNoStrictAliasing.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AgentsStarter.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/ApplicationPool2/AppTypes.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/agent/UstRouter/FilterSupport.o /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645/gems/passenger-5.0.14/buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lrt /tmp/passenger.1h1qwc2/pcre-8.34/.libs/libpcre.a -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz
objs/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.o: In function `ngx_ssl_check_host':
/home/deploy/source/nginx-1.9.3/src/event/ngx_event_openssl.c:2945: undefined reference to`X509_check_host'
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.o: In function `ngx_http_ssl_merge_srv_conf':
/home/deploy/source/nginx-1.9.3/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.c:650: undefined reference to`SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/deploy/source/nginx-1.9.3'
make: *** [build] Error 2

Can someone help with a possible solution?

thanks